Where to file H4 petition?
I am currently living in Virginia and on J-2 status. I want to change status from J2 to H4 using Form I-539. The USCIS H-1B receipt number for the main H-1B applicant starts with IOE. I am unsure where to mail the petition as there are two options on the USCIS website:

J nonimmigrants and their dependents should file at: USCIS Attn: I-539 P.O. Box 660166 Dallas, TX 75266-0166
H-4 Spouse of an H-1B Nonimmigrant Filing Form I-539 Separately From the H-1B Principal Nonimmigrant or Filing Concurrently with Form I-765 for Category (c)(26) should file at the USCIS Phoenix Lockbox if the receipt number of your H-1B principal spouse’s most recent Form I-797, Notice of Action, (approving their Form I-129) begins with WAC, SRC, or IOE: USCIS Attn: H-4 P.O. Box 20400 Phoenix, AZ 85036-0400
Note: I cannot apply online as there is a minor involved. The main H-1B applicant's status is being changed from J1 to H1B (case pending USCIS decision). I am guessing option 1, but wasn't quite sure. Thanks


You should follow the instructions for the status you are changing to (in this case, H4). So you can either file I-539 online or mail it to the Phoenix Lockbox.
